# Deploying Acumatica ERP on MS Azure

Tags: azure, acumatica, erp

I am a student following an IT course at University and now proceeding to the final year of the course. I will be doing my dissertation based on ERPs and BI within digital health environment. The ERP chosen for this project is Acumatica.

How to check if I am eligible to deploy Acumatica on Microsoft Azure with my current University email? If so, what services and procedures are required in order to deploy the said ERP on Azure? If I am not eligible, would it be possible to suggest alternatives in which I could utilize/deploy Acumatica ERP?

Moreover, I have accessed Microsoft Azure using the University email account and linked it to my personal account in order to access Azure; and now need to verify if with my University email privileges I could deploy Acumatica on Azure.

Also, I have researched on how to deploy it, however, they state a storage account is required which I currently do not have.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which kind of Azure services that you but for the deployment with Azure you can get the references with this link https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6bdba7d6-1b17-4a20-82e6-c66542a4f5dd

Comment: When I try to follow those steps it states that I should "Create a free account". I have linked my University account and logged in with it but I cannot understand why I have to create another account.